# How to send long message using AT Commands, vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, sms, at-command

```
        strMessage = SplitSMS(_dtMessageQueue.Rows(0)("Response"), 155)

        For i As Integer = 0 To strMessage.GetUpperBound(0)
            Try
                With SerialPort1
                    .Write("AT" & vbCrLf)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                    .Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000)
                    .Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & _dtMessageQueue.Rows(0)("MobileNo") & Chr(34) & vbCrLf)
                    .Write(strMessage(i) & Chr(26) & vbCrLf)
                    Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000)
                End With
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        Next
```

I have written the above code in order to send SMS from my vb.net application to a Mobile phone.

Is it possible to send the message without splitting message,

I want to send the message as one.

Comment: Do you get an error simply sending SMS with a single AT+CMGS issue?

Comment: No error, but when i try to send more than 160 char,  the message will split into multiple messages. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so there's probably a limitation in your device's +CMGS implementation. There's a last advice I can provide: just compose the sms in PDU mode so that the several messages are received as a single one (there's a flag for concatenated messages). I cannot build an answer out of this because I worked on it years ago and I honestly don't remember details (it's not trivial creating consistent pdu messages!). You will have to study the standard, I'm afraid...

Comment: Ok, Thanks, can you give me some sites? where i can study this topic. Specialy in composing sms in PDU mode.Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMS length is limited to 160 seven-bit characters. It was subsequently codified into the SMPP signalling protocol that transmits SMS and is limited to precisely 140 bytes (or 1120 bits).

try reading [this](https://www.twilio.com/docs/glossary/what-sms-character-limit)

Comment: Thank you for the info, But Is there any other way ma'am/sir? Like Using AT-Commands to send long message without splitting into multiple message. Thanks